# timeout in MYSQL

Tags: java, mysql, timeout

I have a java application that has long running processes and interact with db.  It keeps getting the following:

```
The last packet successfully received from the server was 3,601,168 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 3,601,166 milliseconds ago.
```

The remote server has a wait_timeout 354600 which is in seconds.  What could be wrong?

Comment: It is timing out! [obvious] Anyway, it would make a lot more sense if wait_timeout was 3546000, as it is in milliseconds and is equal to about 59min. Which is very close to the number in the message.

Comment: @Cassio: but it was 354600, and I think it is seconds, but ms according to the doc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be a number of problems, but I don't believe wait_timeout is the culprit if your last packet was sent/received about 3600s ago and wait_timeout is 354600s. You could have lost the connection to the server or any other of a number of things. You need to post more about what your code is doing and more about what you expect to happen and what is actually happening.

- Side question: MySQL was designed to create connections relatively quickly. Have you considered using a connection pool rather than continuously using one connection explicitly?

As for Cassio's comment under the question... wait_timeout is in seconds. [MySQL Docs - wait_timeout](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout)